# Remove overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis

How to remove all polygons in QGIS from layer A which are at least partially overlapped by any polygon from layer B?

Geoprocessing tools / Difference is not an option as it will remove only overlaping parts of the polygons from layer A and not whole polygons.

Comment: First thought: select by location and then just hit delete button

Comment: @MrXsquared you mean manually? Because there are thousands of polygons in both layeys.

Comment: Select by location is a tool where you can set conditions - it runs automatically: `Menu Vector / Research Tools / Select by location`

Comment: ...and then start editing and Delete button, save edits and stop editing

Comment: Actually I settled on PostGIS where I can also apply some buffering and is faster when working with huge datasets. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. Use **`select by location`** from processing toolbox and use **`intersect`** as geometric predicate. Then start the edit mode of your layer and hit the delete button, then save your edits.

[image]

2. Use **`extract by location`** from processing toolbox and use **`disjoint`** as geometric predicate. This will create a new layer, containing only the features that meet your criteria.

[image]